# Resize WPF application until remain only the window bar

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window-resize

It's a way to modify the height on the window until remains only the window bar? Right now I use to set the height of the window to 0 **BUT** still remain some content above the window bar (that white and gray area), I want to remove this completely and leave only the window bar:

I use MVVM so binding is needed:

XAML:

```
Width="{Binding MainWindowWidthSize, Mode=TwoWay}"
Height="{Binding MainWindowHeightSize, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

C#

```
 public void TriggerFloatingMode(object obj)
            {
                if (!_isFloatingModeEnabled)
                {
                    MainWindowWidthSize = 500;
                    MainWindowHeightSize = 0;
                    _isFloatingModeEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MainWindowWidthSize = 1000;
                    MainWindowHeightSize = 560;
                    _isFloatingModeEnabled = false;
    
                }
    
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code `WindowStyle="None"` in the Window tag and enter the following code at the bottom of the Window tag

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
       <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
           <Setter.Value>
             <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="0" ResizeBorderThickness="2" CaptionHeight="0"></WindowChrome>
           </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

*In the above code, change `TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"` to the name of your window `local: your window name`*

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution with your code could be

```
<Window x:Class="YourWindow.MainWindow"    
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid Height="{Binding MainWindowHeightSize  }" Width="{Binding MainWindowWidthSize }">
</Grid>
</Window>
```